# Intersect LINQ query

Tags: c#, .net, linq

If I have an IEnumerable where ClassA exposes an ID property of type long.
Is it possible to use a Linq query to get all instances of ClassA with ID belonging to a second IEnumerable?

In other words, can this be done?

```
IEnumerable<ClassA> = original.Intersect(idsToFind....)?
```

where original is an `IEnumerable<ClassA>` and idsToFind is `IEnumerable<long>`.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Yes.

As other people have answered, you can use `Where`, but it will be extremely inefficient for large sets.

If performance is a concern, you can call [`Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675.aspx):

```
var results = original.Join(idsToFind, o => o.Id, id => id, (o, id) => o);
```

If `idsToFind` can contain duplicates, you'll need to either call `Distinct()` on the IDs or on the results or replace `Join` with [`GroupJoin`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534297.aspx)  (The parameters to GroupJoin would be the same).

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thank you.  Somehow, this did not make it in my original quesion but idsToFind = IEnumerable<long>.

Thanks again.

Comment: Any idea at which size of `original` or `idsToFind` the `Join` starts getting more efficient than the `Where`/`Contains` solution? I can imagine that for small lists (maybe 20-30 items) the `Join` has too much overhead?

Comment: To help, you can use this extension method relying on `Join`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59321033/1248177

Answer (score 20):

I will post an answer using `Intersect`.

This is useful if you want to intersect 2 `IEnumerables` of the same type.

First we will need an `EqualityComparer`:

```
    public class KeyEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
    {
        private readonly Func<T, object> keyExtractor;

        public KeyEqualityComparer(Func<T, object> keyExtractor)
        {
            this.keyExtractor = keyExtractor;
        }

        public bool Equals(T x, T y)
        {
            return this.keyExtractor(x).Equals(this.keyExtractor(y));
        }

        public int GetHashCode(T obj)
        {
            return this.keyExtractor(obj).GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

Secondly we apply the `KeyEqualityComparer` to the `Intersect` function:

```
var list3= list1.Intersect(list2, new KeyEqualityComparer<ClassToCompare>(s => s.Id));
```

Answer (score 12):

You can do it, but in the current form, you'd want to use the `Where` extension method.

```
var results = original.Where(x => yourEnumerable.Contains(x.ID));
```

`Intersect` on the other hand will find elements that are in both `IEnumerable`'s. If you are looking for just a list of ID's, you can do the following which takes advantage of `Intersect`

```
var ids = original.Select(x => x.ID).Intersect(yourEnumerable);
```

Answer (score 6):

A simple way would be:

```
IEnumerable<ClassA> result = original.Where(a => idsToFind.contains(a.ID));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) method to filter the results:

```
var result = original.Where(o => idsToFind.Contains(o.ID));
```

Answer (score 1):

Naming things is important. Here is an extension method base on the `Join` operator:

```
private static IEnumerable<TSource> IntersectBy<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    IEnumerable<TKey> keys,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
        => source.Join(keys, keySelector, id => id, (o, id) => o);
```

You can use it like this `var result = items.IntersectBy(ids, item => item.id)`.

Answer (score 0):

I've been tripping up all morning on Intersect, and how it doesn't work anymore in core 3, due to it being client side not server side.

From a list of items pulled from a database, the user can then choose to display them in a way that requires children to attached to that original list to get more information.

What use to work was:

```
itemList = _context.Item
        .Intersect(itemList)
        .Include(i => i.Notes)
        .ToList();
```

What seems to now work is:

```
itemList = _context.Item
        .Where(item => itemList.Contains(item))
        .Include(i => i.Notes)
        .ToList();
```

This seems to be working as expected, without any significant performance difference, and is really no more complicated than the first.