# How can I intersect two different .NET lists by a single property?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to filter my first list of Foo's based on some values in a second list of Baa's.

For example.

Here's [an example I put up on .NET Fiddle](http://dotnetfiddle.net/qYNjn3) ...

```
var foos = new List<Foo>
{
    new Foo { Name = "Leia" },
    new Foo { Name = "Han Solo" },
    new Foo { Name = "Chewbacca" },
    new Foo { Name = "Luke" },
};

    var baas = new List<Baa>
{
    new Baa { Alias = "aaaaa" },
    new Baa { Alias = "bbbb" },
    new Baa { Alias = "Leia" },
    new Baa { Alias = "Luke" }
};

// Expected output:
// List<Foo> results = Foo { "Leia" } and Foo { "Luke" };
```

See how I'm asking for: Filter the first list (by `Name`) by the second lists `Alias` property.

and that will return a List of `Foo` with 2 results in it?

Any clues?

Comment: If your collections contain a lot of items, it might be wise to use `HashSet` instead of `List`. Checking if an item is contained in a `HashSet` is a O(1) operation, which can greatly improve the speed of computing the intersection. There is a dedicated method for this in the `HashSet` class, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb918911%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: *VERY* good point @Benlitz ! In my scenario, each list will be a few items only. But the answer(s) really help me for future dev where I might have to deal with list intersections. Would love to see some example code using the `Intersects` keyword if the two collections were `HashSet`'s.

Comment: @Pure.Krome You can't use `Intersect` because the lists are of two different types.

Comment: Ah! `HashSet` is against two of the same type. gotcha.

Comment: Yep I misread the question, however you can still do it if you use a `HashSet<object>` and provides your own implementation of `IEqualityComparer` that can compare Foos and Baas. But that will lead to unsafe code so it should be done only if you have real performance issues and in the most internal/private way possible. I tested intersecting two collections of 10000 items, got 1400ms using lists and <1ms with hashset. Sample code here: http://pastebin.com/E6SJRDnr

Answer (score 10):

You can use `Any` on the list of `baas`:

```
foos.Where(f => baas.Any(b => b.Alias == f.Name));
```

Or use a join (cleaner in query syntax):

```
var query = 
    from f in foos
    join b in baas on f.Name equals b.Alias
    select f;
```

[Here's the code](http://dotnetfiddle.net/9YgkF2) in a full working .NET Fiddle.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675.aspx):

```
var results = foos.Join(baas, f => f.Name, b => b.Alias, (f, b) => f);
```

Similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2381086/74757).