# create new list by selecting objects where two lists are equal

Tags: c#

I have two lists, StockOld & StockNew. They are a custom type called 'Stock'. Stock has 5 properties but for my purposes if the two properties, isin & region are the same in both lists the objects should be treated as equal. What I want if to create a new list that selects all the objects that are equal in StockOld & StockNew. Hopefully the example below will help demonstrate what I mean.

```
StockOld                    StockNew                  Result I would like
ISIN      Region            ISIN        Region        ISIN        Region

ABC1      UK                DFG3        EU            ABC1        UK
ERT4      US                ABC1        UK            LMN8        EU
LMN8      EU                PLK2        EU
                            LMN8        EU
```

I have created a comparer class that implements IEqualityComparer, please see below.

```
 public class ComparerISINRegion : IEqualityComparer<Stock>
    {
        public bool Equals(Stock x, Stock y)
        {
            return x.ISIN == y.ISIN && x.Region == y.Region;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Stock obj)
        {
            int hash = 17;
            hash = hash * 23 + (obj.ISIN ?? "").GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + (obj.Region ?? "").GetHashCode();
            return hash;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb355408%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to extract the "equal" elements between two lists:

```
var newLst = StockOld.Intersect(StockNew, new ComparerISINRegion());
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is truly the only way you wish to compare Stocks, I would recommend you override the *Equals* operator on your actual Stock class (see MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx). This will better follow OOP practices, as your custom Stock class will now contain your Equals and GetHashCode methods.

Once these methods are overridden, you may use **LINQ** to form a new list via the following:

`IList<Stock> newList = list1.Intersect(list2);`

Alternatively, you could avoid overriding these methods and compare specific properties with a LINQ where or join clause (see [Intersect LINQ query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381049/intersect-linq-query)).